# Does $E[X] < \infty$ imply $X<\infty$ almost surely

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation

Suppose that there is a positive random variable $X$. 
Also, assume that $E[X]<\infty$. Does that imply $X < \infty$ almost surely?

The last answer on [a forum](http://mathhelpforum.com/advanced-statistics/50530-expectation-infinite-sum.html) seem to suggest that it does. 
However, what if $$X=N\quad \text{w.p. }\frac{1}{N^3}$$
for $N\in {\mathbb N}$.
Isn't the implication false?

Comment: Yes, if $X$ is infinite on a set $A$ of positive measure, then $X \ge \infty \cdot 1_A$, and so $E X = \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\{X < \infty\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{X = n\}$ in your case. Also note that since $\sum \frac{1}{N^3}$ is not $1$, you need to scale your probabilities accordingly.

Comment: _Why_ to you put the "equals" sign _outside_ of MathJax?  (I changed it.)  It appears in a smaller font and without proper spacing when you do that.  (I am continually amazed at the weirdness of the way some people use MathJax here.)

Comment: @Hardy: Thanks for correcting it.